# how can I iterate around an arraylist of objects in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, object

I am writing a simple Checkout program in python
My checkout class is

```
 Class Checkoutregister


 product1 = Product(510, 'milk', 6)
 product2 = Product(511, 'coke', 3)
 product3 = Product(512, 'chicken', 10)
 product4 = Product(513, 'shirt', 40)
 product5 = Product(514, 'kitkat', 4)
 list=[]
```

This is my product class

```
class Product:
def __init__(self,barcode,name,price):
    self.barcode=barcode
    self.name=name
    self.price=price
```

I am writing a function to insert the products to the list and print the list..but I am getting problem while printing the list

```
 def insertProduct():
        Checkoutregister.list.insert(0,Checkoutregister.product1)
        print Checkoutregister.list
```

The print statement prints like

```
[<Product.Product instance at 0x04AEB6C0>]
```

how can I print the list and how can I iterate around the list to print all the inserted products in the list when I add all the products in the list

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `_str_` method to your product class

Try:

```
class Product:
  def __init__(self,barcode,name,price):
    self.barcode=barcode
    self.name=name
    self.price=price
  def __str__(self):
        return "ProdName: "+self.name+" Barcode: "+str(self.barcode)+" Price: $"+str(self.price)

product1 = Product(510, 'milk', 6)

print(product1)
```

This will print `Product` objects like:

```
ProdName: milk Barcode: 510 Price: $6
```

If you want to have a `list[]` of `Product` objects that you then want to iterate through and print each one, that would look like the following:

```
# create our products
product1 = Product(510, 'milk', 6)
product2 = Product(420, 'hotdog buns', 3)
# create a list to hold our products
list_of_prods = []
# add our products to the list[]
list_of_prods.append(product1)
list_of_prods.append(product2)
# iterate over our list[] with a simple for:each loop
for prod in list_of_prods:
  print(prod)
```

This would print out all of the `Product`'s in `list_of_prods[]`.
Output looks like:

```
ProdName: milk Barcode: 510 Price: $6
ProdName: hotdog buns Barcode: 420 Price: $3
```

From your original question, it looks like you were trying to accomplish this by creating a `Checkoutregister` class - the idea there would be the same, and your `insertProduct()` method would just need to add products to the `Checkoutregister.list`.

Comment: Thank you. But i want to store a number of products in an array and display them later.how can i do that